# JavaScript function on interval being erratic

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, setinterval

I'm working on a personal website and I'm trying to make a small script to change a certain part of the html every few seconds (three seconds at the moment).

It switches the text at the bottom from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

EDIT: The entire html.erb page looks like this

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>I make <strong id="noun"><%= @word %></strong>.</p>

<script>
var words = ["programs", "video games", "software", "music", "board games", "websites"];

var shift = setInterval(function(){ 
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
    $("#noun").text(word);
}, 3000);

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   clearInterval(shift);
};
</script>
```

It works perfectly the first time, but if I go to one of the links in the navbar (for example Resume) and the return home, it acts almost like it has two intervals and will switch words twice as often. This stacks and I can get it to switch words 5 or 6 times faster than it should. However, on refresh, it goes back to normal.

What's the issue and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is that script in?

Comment: It's currently just in a script tag, planned on moving into the assets/javasripts after getting something working since I'd have to lookup how to reference it when it's not a tag

Comment: And where is that tag?

Comment: @JonasW. I updated the question to contain the entire page home.html.erb

Comment: long story short, remove turbolinks

Comment: @wiesion thanks that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a SPA,
ensure that you're clearing the interval to prevent it from continuing (and prevent memory leaks)

use`clearInterval(shift)` before you navigate.

Comment: React : ``componentWillUnmount() { clearInterval(this.myINterval)}``

Angularjs : ``$scope.$on('destroy' , ()=> {clearInterval(this.interval)}``

Comment: I'm struggling to research how to run a function when I leave a page, jQuery has a deprecated function unload(), but that's all I could find. I'm not using react, any suggestions?